# How do I return a table from a function?

Tags: oracle, function, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle 12c and Oracle SQL Developer to create a package. My intent is to pass a value to the package from a SQL statement, like `SELECT * FROM table(test2.get_ups(0));`. I want to return a table like executing a SQL SELECT statement in the IDE.

This is my package. When I try to compile I get the following error:

`PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "FOR" to continue.`

How do I fix this?

Here is the package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test2 AS

    TYPE measure_record IS RECORD(
       x_start VARCHAR2(50), 
       x_end VARCHAR2(50), 
       trip_count NUMBER);

    TYPE measure_table IS TABLE OF measure_record;

    FUNCTION get_ups(x number)
        RETURN measure_table
        PIPELINED;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test2 AS

    FUNCTION get_ups(x number) RETURN measure_table
        PIPELINED as

        cursor temp_cur is 
          SELECT x1, x2, count(*) FROM t1 WHERE x1 = x;

            for cur_rec in temp_cur
            loop
              pipe row(cur_rec);
            end loop;

        RETURN;
    END get_ups;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have either to move the CURSOR into the DECLARE section or use an anonymous cursor like so:

```
FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT x1, x2, count(*) FROM t1 WHERE x1 = x)
LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems: function definitions require a `BEGIN`. this function must return an instance of a variable instead of a cursor, and a `GROUP BY` is required for the query.

Each change below has a comment.

```
create table t1(x1 number, x2 number);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test2 AS

    TYPE measure_record IS RECORD(
       x_start VARCHAR2(50), 
       x_end VARCHAR2(50), 
       trip_count NUMBER);

    TYPE measure_table IS TABLE OF measure_record;

    FUNCTION get_ups(x number)
        RETURN measure_table
        PIPELINED;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test2 AS

    FUNCTION get_ups(x number) RETURN measure_table
        PIPELINED as

        temp measure_record; --Add temporary variable to hold the cursor values.

        cursor temp_cur is 
          SELECT x1, x2, count(*) FROM t1 WHERE x1 = x GROUP BY x1, x2;  --Add "GROUP BY".
    BEGIN --Add "BEGIN".
            for cur_rec in temp_cur
            loop
              --Assign the values to the temporary variable.
              temp.x_start := cur_rec.x1;
              temp.x_end := cur_rec.x2;
              temp.trip_count := cur_rec."COUNT(*)";
              pipe row(temp); --Pipe the variable, not the cursor.
            end loop;

        RETURN;
    END get_ups;
END;
/

select * from table(test2.get_ups(1));
```

Comment: By and large, I agree. The cursor is parameterized so it should look slightly  different, right? Like, `cursor temp_cur (x NUMBER) is `...

Comment: @PatrickBacon The cursor can reference the function parameter and `X` doesn't need to be passed in through a cursor parameter.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That doesn't work for me on 12.2.  As far as I know PL/SQL record types do not have a default constructor and must be assembled piece by piece.  If the record and table type was defined as a SQL type then it should work.

Comment: @JonHeller, Yes you are completely right, I missed that.